# Set csquote macros in AUCTeX preference to work also with included files

Tags: emacs, auctex, csquotes

I use to keep most of my documents in separate *branch* files and then `/include` them in the main *tree* document. Of course I don't need a preamble for all separate files.

In my AUCTeX preferences I set

```lisp
;; " expands into csquotes macros
(setq  LaTeX-csquotes-open-quote "\\enquote{"
       LaTeX-csquotes-close-quote "}")
```

but still I can't benefit from it in the *branch* files since they have no preamble and no `\usepackage{csquotes}` command.

Is there any workaround, so to have the AUCTeX preferences working for all .tex document and not only where the package `csquote` is explicitly indicated?

Comment: Do you have the master file set in the local variables?  Something like: `%%% Local Variables: %%% TeX-master: "masterfile" %%% End:` (where each block of `%%%` starts a newline)..?

Comment: @jon Not sure what you mean by "master file set in local variables" Do you mean If I have any declaration as preamble of the included files? My included files don't have any declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as AUCTeX has no practical way of knowing which file is the 'parent' to another file, it cannot know you have loaded a specific package without some help.  The best thing to do is make use of the `Local Variables` setting, which should appear at the end (or very near to the end) of each file.  The following will tell AUCTeX that the file is indeed the/a master file (which it will assume in absence of any other information):

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-master: "master"
%%% End:
```

Or:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Now if you have `\include`d or `\input`ed files, you need to tell AUCTeX of this relationship.  Imagine your master is called `maindoc.tex` and it includes a file called `chapter01.tex`; then in `chapter01.tex`, you could have:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-master: "maindoc"
%%% End:
```

Now AUCTeX should know that when you ask for a LaTeX or BibTeX (etc.) run, it should run the command on `maindoc`, not `chapter01`.  It should also realize that the main file has loaded `csquotes` and give you access to those commands.

Of course, if you are using `emacs`, you'll want to set a few things in your `.emacs`.  I use in this connection, for example:

```lisp
;; AUCTeX + Reftex       
(setq TeX-parse-self     t)   ; Enable parse on load 
(setq TeX-auto-save      t)   ; Enable parse on save 
(setq-default TeX-master nil) ; Query for master file <-- this one is key for this question

;; Turn on RefTeX for AUCTeX
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-enable-partial-scans           t)
(setq reftex-save-parse-info                t)
(setq reftex-use-multiple-selection-buffers t)
```

In general, local variables can be pretty useful.  For instance, you can set which TeX engine you want to use with; maybe you want to use `lualatex` on this file:

```
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
```

Or which modes you want (rather redundant, but):

```
%%% mode: latex
%%% mode: flyspell
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
```

... and so on.  There's lots of options.

One final thing to note: if you add these variables manually after AUCTeX has already parsed the file, the changes won't be noticed until you re-open the file, or use `C-c C-n` to force emacs to re-parse the buffer.

Comment: Stupid question probably, but if my "maindoc" is in the parent directory--and the chapters in the `/chapter` directory--how do I refer to it without using the absolute path?

Comment: @Francesco -- If I have a multi-level setup, as long as I point AUCTeX correctly to the masterfile, all is well.  It would give me something like: `%%% TeX-master: "../maindoc"` (i.e., a relative path).

Comment: Important to make sure the local variables are at the end of the file (not as a preamble)